# The Diamond Game

Tags: game

**Barkeep:**

> Well hello there, come to play the famous Diamond Game?
>
> The rules are notoriously simple. Here's an ace of diamonds card (it's larger than normal), and here are a pile of pennies. We each take turns to place pennies on the card. Whoever is first not to be able to fit a penny onto the card loses.
>
> Tell you what, you go first this time. Put a tenner on it. If you win, you'll get twenty!

How can the player guarantee that they win every time, regardless of how the barkeep plays?

---

*For the purposes of the game, assume that both players are able to exactly follow any rule or process, regardless of its complexity.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, I heard about this puzzle and resolved it once, so it's easy for me, sorry.

To ensure, that you'll win,

> you must start at the very center of the card. The other player will put a coin at a random position. You just have to put yours symmetrically to the other's, with the center of your first. Since, there will be for every opponent coin a symmetrical place, you will win with this method.

Comment: It's always funny to see people try this in go. They get rekt

Comment: @JacobGoulden Look, if somebody will put an another answer, I will upvote it. If this answering method is not suitable for Puzzle SE, then okay, I learned from this.

Comment: @Lasoloz I think it is perfect for Puzzle SE

Comment: @Lordofdark Okay, thank you. I actually added the resolved part, because first I did not think that my words imply that I just copy-pasted. Unfortunately I'm not native English speaker.